# Calculating MAP50 for a segmentation task

Tags: python, image, object

I have built a instance segmentation model. I want to make a prediction on the new image and want to check the robustness of the model. I have the masks for the ground truth and also the masks for the prediction I have made. How can I calculate mAP50 ? I have around 4 different classes in my prediction mask and ground truth.